# Is it possible connect to a PPTP VPN with just one line?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, vpn, pptp

I have a few VPN servers and I find it quite tedious to create several configurations for each server.

In a perfect world I'd love to do something like this:

```
pptp 168.24.15.65 username password
```

And that would connect me right away, is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

`pppd pty "pptp SERVER --nolaunchpppd" file /etc/ppp/options.pptp user USER password PASSWORD`

`require-mppe-128` option (could be enabled in options.pptp) is often needed for windows servers.

After connection usually configuration of routing is needed. Something like this:
`ip route add 10/8 dev ppp0`